# How to do a ratio between 2 agrregated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return a ratio between 'Pocet starych' (existing clients) a 'Pocet novych' (new clients) in this particular year.
I've come up with:

```
    SELECT
    Pomer = 1.0*
        (SUM(CASE
        (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(KliRc)
            FROM 
                dbo.Smlouvy 
            WHERE VyplacenaCastka > 0
            GROUP BY 
                KliRC
            HAVING
                COUNT(KliRC) > 1 -- Pocet starych
    ) When 0  Then 1 Else 0 End ) 
    / SUM(CASE
        (
        SELECT 
                COUNT(KliRc)
            FROM 
                dbo.Smlouvy
            WHERE VyplacenaCastka > 0 
            GROUP BY 
                KliRC
            HAVING
                COUNT(KliRc) = 1 -- Pocet novych
        ) When 1 Then 1 Else 0 End ))
        FROM 
            dbo.Smlouvy
WHERE
    DATEPART(YYYY, DatumZadosti) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())
```

KliRC = personal identification number

Which returns

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.
>
> Blockquote

Any help would be aprreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a `SUM` in front of the `CASE`? This should be causing the error message.

Comment: I think you have error in your logic: `When 0  Then 1 Else 0 End` willl always return 0 due to `HAVING COUNT(KliRC) > 1`.

Comment: Yes, it's a garbage....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query contains errors in your logic too, but I assume you want to write this:

```
WITH Grouped AS(    
    SELECT 
        Cnt = COUNT(KliRc)
    FROM 
        dbo.Smlouvy 
    WHERE VyplacenaCastka > 0
    GROUP BY 
        KliRC
)
SELECT 1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN Cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Grouped
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, it really helped me. And what if I'd want to look in the database for all past records and return only the ratio of new/existing clients who made a contract this year?

Comment: You can add date filter here: `WHERE VyplacenaCastka > 0 AND <AnotherFilter>`